# Why does the key not seem to work when using the DES_DECRYPT function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, encryption, des

When I run the following code it does not seem the use the key to decrypt the data?

I receive the same results whether I add the key or not when decrypting.
It may be relevant to know that the data was encrypted in nodejs (Code Below)

```
SELECT 
     des_decrypt(firstName, 'MYSECRYPTKEY') Name, firstName
FROM users
```

Encryption code in node

```
const enc = value => {
  if (value !== null && value !== "" && value !== undefined) {
    var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(process.env.AES_KEY);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(value, keyHex, {
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
      padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return encrypted.toString();
  } else {
    return value;
  }
};
```

Example of results

```
Name            firstName
Hv1eN7CLj1k=    Hv1eN7CLj1k=
bc0vsKnLa00=    bc0vsKnLa00=
OhhE6Va+tg0=    OhhE6Va+tg0=
02RJonbm2jY=    02RJonbm2jY=
```

Comment: Did you read [the manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_des-decrypt)

Comment: Pretty sure the UTF 8 encoding on the key in CrypoJS makes it so MySQL cant decrypt it

Comment: Yes, read the manual page.... using it as described...

Comment: Have tried to UTF8 encode the string too in MySQL

Comment: Also, how does this explain the fact that the results are not been decrypted?  They are exactly the same in both columns